# TFS Process Editor error "the given path's format is not supported"

Tags: tfs

If I use the TFS process editor from within Visual Studio 2017:
Menu:  Tools->Process Editor->Work Item Types->Open WIT from Server.
I get the error "the given path's format is not supported".

I can use witadmin to export to and xml file, but the import does not give an error and appears to work - but does not as the changes do not appear within the TFS workitems.

What is the path format that it is referring to and how can I correct it?

[image]

Comment: What's the detail version of Visual Studio do you use? Have you checked the issue on other machines? Does it occur on all the machines? I tested with `Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.5.2` on my side, everthing works as expected.

Comment: What's the detail version of VS 2017? Can you reproduce this issue on another machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause.  This is a bug when you try to use process editor with SSL.  When I use it over http it works fine.
[Using VS 2017 & TFS2017]

Answer (score 1):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

1. Uninstall the [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor) extension from VS:

   - In the Visual Studio menu, go to: `Tools > Extensions And Updates` select the extension to uninstall.
2. [Clear Visual Studio Component Cache](https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md) :

   - 1) Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
   - 2) Delete the directory : `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0\ComponentModelCache`
   - 3) Restart Visual Studio.
3. Re-install the [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor) extension for VS.

If that still not work, just try to reset the user data, then try it again:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE

devenv.exe /resetuserdata
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and detailed steps.   Sadly I still have the same error.

Comment: @simon831 Can you share the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see `.wit` files sitting beside the XML versions of the work items on the file system? Those would get generated if you opened the WITs in the old versions of TFS Power Tools and need to be deleted so the new editor can generate them again. This used to happen switched between version of Visual Studio/Power Tools before the new Extension was released.

Comment: No, its just xml.  I have only ever used VS2017 and the new power tools.

Answer (score 0):

In our case ssl was not used for configuration, I faced the same problem.

Update of VS etc, didn't work, I have not reinstalled the feature.

Resolution in my case:
TFS 2018 is configured to use public URL (not fqdn of vm). Adding TFS by public url faced the problem. Using an additional hosts entry for public IP + internal VM Name solved the problem in my case.